# Sharing Outlook mail rules

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, mail-rule

If one user has a set of useful mail rules they want to give to someone else, Outlook doesn't appear to support this properly. Even if the destination mailbox has all the correct folders created with the correct names, it seems Outlook uses the internal guid identifier, and when one imports the rules they are all marked with errors about folders not existing.

Is there a reliable way to export Outlook mail rules from one user to another?

Answer (score 3):

In `Tools|Rules and Alerts...`, click the `Options` button on the RHS. There's an `Export` button on that dialog that allows you to export your rules.

[image]

Comment: This exports and imports all rules not just one or a few.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this is a deficiency in Outlook.  It looks like not much has changed as of outlook.exe version 15.0.4711.1003.

There's a 3rd party plug-in called "Power Rules Manager" by Sperry Software that appears to, among other things, allow import/export to an editable XML format. I haven't used this tool myself since it appears that it would require a separate license for every user that wanted to either create or use share-able rules.